# Ошибка сегментации при заполнении динамического массива

Tags: массивы, c, gcc

Есть такой код:

```
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef unsigned int _alenght;

void free_square_matrix(int ***m, _alenght size)
{
for (_alenght i = 0; i < size; i++)
    free(*m[i]);
free(*m);
}

void fill_square_matrix(int ***m, _alenght n)
{
printf("start\n");
for (_alenght i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("l\n");
    for (_alenght j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("c\n");
        *m[i][j] = 666;
    }
};
}
void print_square_matrix(const int **m, _alenght size)
{
printf("\nМатрица %ix%i\n№\t", size, size);
for (_alenght i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("*%i\t", i);
printf("\n\n");
for (_alenght i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("*%i\t", i);
    for (_alenght j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        printf(" %i\t", m[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
}
int main(void)
{
printf("Введите порядок матрицы А: ");
_alenght n;
while (scanf("%u", &n) != 1 || n < 1) {
    printf("Введите порядок матрицы А: ");
    __fpurge(stdin);
}

int **m = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
int **e = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
for (_alenght i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    m[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    e[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
}

fill_square_matrix(&m, n);
print_square_matrix((const int **)m, n);
free_square_matrix(&m, n);
return 0;
}
```

Компилиурем, выпоняем:

```
lal@local ~/dev/univer/04 $ ./04 
Введите порядок матрицы А: 2
start
l
c
c
l
c
Ошибка сегментирования
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли о [приоритете операций](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence): индексирование выполняется перед разыменованием.

Кроме того, вам не обязательно передавать `m` «по ссылке»*, вы ведь не меняете его. Итого:

```
void fill_square_matrix(int ***pm, _alenght n)
{
    printf("start\n");
    for (_alenght i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("l\n");
        for (_alenght j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("c\n");
            (*pm)[i][j] = 666; // <-----------
        }
    }
}
```

или лучше просто

```
void fill_square_matrix(int **m, _alenght n)
{
    printf("start\n");
    for (_alenght i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("l\n");
        for (_alenght j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("c\n");
            m[i][j] = 666;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: если вы имеете в виду длину, то у вас опечатка: length

---

*Я в курсе, что формально говоря в C нету передачи по ссылке, а есть лишь передача указателя по значению.